# How to get Public IP in Electron App before windows user logged in

Tags: node.js, electron

I have build an Electron application for desktop activity tracking. Currently what's happening here is when Windows is boot up and user login to windows. Then Electron App automatically launched and starts tracking activity. What I want to achieve is when Windows is boot up I want to fetch Public IP before user login to windows account. Thank you in advance.